# How do I move my daughter to my manor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I'm not married, but I have adopted a daughter and she is staying in Whiterun. I would like to move her to Lakeview Manor. It is completely furnished and everything and I have told her that we were going to move, but all it did was give me the speech option saying "Nevermind, we're staying here," and leaves my daughter ([Lucia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lucia)) upset.

What else do I have to do to make the manor appropriate to move to?

Comment: Just to confirm; you have a fully furnished Main Hall, yes? Also, if you furnished your manor by purchasing from your steward rather than building- That option is notoriously slow, and it might be some time before all the furniture appears. The child's bed and/or the container they require to be present in order to move in might be in the queue to appear.

Answer (score 3):

You need beds and containers.
Your child or wife won't move if you don't have enough beds / containers.

Comment: Specifically, you need a *child's bed* and a specific container that is often next to said bed.

Answer (score 1):

In your Falkreath House, make sure in your Bedroom wing you have both child's beds and chests, since you have a child. if you don't have the bedroom wing, furnished the upstairs room where you have to furnish the single beds and the drawer. If you did all of that and you still have a problem, download the [Unofficial Hearthfire Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25127/?) to fix this problem.